# Using CDI except a Java Web Application

Tags: security, dependency-injection, aspectj, cdi, shiro

From Doc i m trying to learn Context and Dependency injection .
[In tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbju.html)  CDI seems can be only use  in a Web application.Can i use CDI in a Java Console project ? And How? I added libraries like javax.enterprice.deploy and cdi-api.I m trying to test Apache Shiro i referenced this  [part of](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2013/01/#DeclarativeRestrictionInBeanMethods) Balusc detailed tutorial  but i need to manage this without JSF and web Appli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.1.5.Final/en-US/html_single/#d0e5335

Yes, it can be used in an SE environment, though many of the scopes do not work, nor really make sense, in an SE environment.